# ¿Como puedo subir archivos a google drive desde codeigniter utilizando la API de google?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-drive

Estoy creando una aplicación web para registrar alumnos con codeigniter y quiero hacer que las fotos que se suban al sitio web se almacenen en Google Drive y a la vez mostrarlos en el sitio web. 
tengo este código creado en el controlador

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 Class Subir extends CI_CONTROLLER
 {
    function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
     }


 public function index()
 {          
      $url = base_url('subir');
      require_once './application/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
      require_once './application/libraries/google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
      $client = new Google_Client();
      $client->setClientId('aqui va mi id');
      $client->setClientSecret(' aqui va mi secret id');
      $client->setRedirectUri($url);
      $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
      if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
          $_SESSION['accessToken'] = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
          header('location:'.$url);exit;
      } elseif (!isset($_SESSION['accessToken'])) {
          $client->authenticate();
      }
      $files= array();
      $dir = dir('./public/files');
      while ($file = $dir->read()) {
          if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
              $files[] = $file;
          }
      }
      $dir->close();
      if (!empty($_POST)) {
          $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['accessToken']);
          $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
          $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
          $file = new Google_DriveFile();
          foreach ($files as $file_name) {
              $file_path = './public/files/'.$file_name;
              $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
              $file->setTitle($file_name);
              $file->setDescription('This is a '.$mime_type.' document');
              $file->setMimeType($mime_type);
              $service->files->insert(
                  $file,
                  array(
                      'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                      'mimeType' => $mime_type
                  )
              );
          }
          finfo_close($finfo);
          header('location:'.$url);exit;
      }
      $datos['files'] = $files;
      $datos['url'] = $url;
    $this->load->view('subir',$datos);

 }
}
?>
```

y este es el código de la vista

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Google Drive Example App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach ($files as $file) { ?>
            <li><?php echo $file; ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Bryam, para mejorar el formato de tu pregunta y así aumentar las posibilidades de poder ayudarte, te recomiendo que revises la página de ayuda sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Tenés algo que podamos ir viendo de tu código? así es más fácil ayudarte. Para comenzar te recomiento: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads .Saludos!!

Comment: Hola Rubén, gracias por tu sugerencia, hasta el momento no tengo nada creado y la documentacion que se presenta en el enlace que me compartiste la he probado y no ha sido eficiente

Comment: composer desde la carpeta app y activas el autoloader en el config luego sigue los pasos de https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php

Comment: me sería mas útil si tuvieras algún proyecto realizado

Comment: Que tal @Bryam, sería bueno que nos digas (compartas) si ya tienes algo codificado, sobre el cual se te pueda apoyar, de lo contrario te recomiendo visitar la documentación oficial https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php para realizar por lo menos la conexión entre tu app y GDrive, y a partir de ahi se te puede auxiliar con las dudas que salgan.

Comment: ya he modificado la pregunta con un código que me funcionó, pero necesito hacer que el archivo que se suba sea seleccionado de un input file pero no se como hacerlo